# Vue.js custom directive doesn't update state dynamically

Tags: typescript, vue-directives

I can't figure out why this directive isn't updating the disabled state of the applied elements when the model is updated.

Can anyone see what I've done wrong?

```
import { DirectiveOptions } from 'vue';    

const disableAllDirective: DirectiveOptions = {

componentUpdated: function (el, binding) {
    if (!binding.value) return;
    const tags = ["input", "button", "textarea", "select"];
    tags.forEach(tagName => {
        const nodes = el.getElementsByTagName(tagName);
        for (let i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
            (<HTMLInputElement>nodes[i]).disabled = true;
            (<HTMLInputElement>nodes[i]).tabIndex = -1;
        }
    });
}
};

export default disableAllDirective;
```

I'm applying the directive like this:

```
<div class="col-5" v-disableAll="!selectedBusinessId">
                    <div class="form-row">
                        <label class="col-1 pt-1 col-form-label-sm">Search:</label>
                        <div class="col-6 form-inline">
                            <input id="txtClientSearch" @change="searchClients" v-model.lazy="clientSearchTerm" placeholder="Facility / Client Name" class="form-control" autocomplete="off" />
                            <input id="txtClientIdSearch" @change="searchClients" v-model.lazy="clientIdSearch" v-validate="'between:1,32767'" data-vv-as="Customer Number" placeholder="Number" class="form-control number-without-spinner" autocomplete="off" type="number" />
                            <button v-on:click="searchClients" class="btn btn-outline-secondary btn-sm form-control-xsm"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
                            <button v-on:click="onClearSearchClick" class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm form-control-xsm"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-auto form-check form-check-inline checkbox checkbox-primary">
                            <input v-model="showInactiveClients" v-on:change="searchClients" id="chkInactive" class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="inActive">
                            <label class="form-check-label no-padding" for="chkInactive">Show Inactive</label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was a basic logic flaw - I was returning out of the function when the binding value was false, instead of setting the 'disabled' attribute according to the binding value.

The corrected code is:

```
import { DirectiveOptions } from 'vue';    

const disableAllDirective: DirectiveOptions = {

componentUpdated: function (el, binding) {
    const tags = ["input", "button", "textarea", "select"];
    tags.forEach(tagName => {
        const nodes = el.getElementsByTagName(tagName);
        for (let i = 0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
            (<HTMLInputElement>nodes[i]).disabled = binding.value;
            (<HTMLInputElement>nodes[i]).tabIndex = -1;
        }
    });
}
};

export default disableAllDirective;
```